# How do I put specific rows together in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a DataGridView control to list down a couple of stuff. However, I want to put specific rows together (NOT putting them all inside a row) based on a condition from the textBox.

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // populate dgv from datatable

            // add columns
            table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Food", typeof(string));

            // add rows
            table.Rows.Add(1, "BBQ");
            table.Rows.Add(2, "Pear");
            table.Rows.Add(3, "Eggs");
            table.Rows.Add(4, "Banana");
            table.Rows.Add(5, "Noodle");
            table.Rows.Add(6, "Orange");
            table.Rows.Add(7, "Mango");
            table.Rows.Add(8, "Beef");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "Fruit" )
            {

            }
        }
```

For example, when I type "Fruit" in the textBox. All the rows that contain a type of fruit will automatically line up on one another, starting at the first row like this:

1. Pear
2. Banana
3. Orange
4. Mango

The same goes for the rest of rows that contain a type of meat when the word "Meat" is typed in the textBox.

Comment: You need to have another column `FoodType` in the datatable and filter the rows based on that column in table when user enters Fruit.

Comment: The above, then [DataView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) `= $"FoodType = '{textBox1.Text}'";`. You should probably pre-define the cathegories that can be the object of a query, though. Using a hand-made DataTable, you could use an `Enum` (to enumerate the cathegories, using the `enum.ToString()` to present the values as text  to a User and the value to query the data). Possibly using a ComboBox as selector instead of a TextBox. Maybe a ComboBox with its AutoComplete feature enabled.

Comment: Anyway, your *put specific rows together* is called a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DataView.RowFilter` property to filter the rows .but you require some column based on that you can filter.

In your case you not had any Fruit, Meat containing column so I add one more column food type. (If you don't want to show this column we can hide it).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Food", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("FoodType", typeof(string));

            // add rows
            table.Rows.Add(1, "BBQ", "Meat");
            table.Rows.Add(2, "Pear","Fruit");
            table.Rows.Add(3, "Eggs", "Eggs");
            table.Rows.Add(4, "Banana", "Fruit");
            table.Rows.Add(5, "Noodle","Veg");
            table.Rows.Add(6, "Orange", "Fruit");
            table.Rows.Add(7, "Mango", "Fruit");
            table.Rows.Add(8, "Beef","Meat");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
           //hide the foodtype column
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["FoodType"].Visible = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(table, "FoodType= '" + textBox1.Text + "'", "FoodType Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            else
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
    }
```

Value is filter based on textbox value. If you want again all value then just empty textbox and click button.

Comment: Appreciate the help!